# Brace highlighting in Visual Studio for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, ide, resharper

Is there a way to get Visual Studio 2008 to do matching brace highlighting for Javascript?

If there is no way to do it in Studio, can it be done using ReSharper?

Thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51088/plugin-for-r-similar-to-coderush-statement-highlight#51107

Comment: Try netbeans -- I use visual studio and am shcoked to see that there is no JS '{' matching. Netbeans does a great job, and now i know why my JS skills in VS are so lacking -- this is a basic, vital feature. Sad... very sad b/c I love VS.

Comment: Does automatic javascript brace highlighting work in Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2? It does not work on mine.., just curious..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Note that Visual Studio will still find a matching brace in JavaScript via Ctrl + ].

Comment: ' Ctrl +]'  ????
To get this closing brace I need to press ctrl + alt + closing brace button.
So this would result in:
' ctrl + (ctrl + alt + closing brace button)' 

How to find the matching end brace with my quertz keyboard?

Answer (score 22):

Here is an extension for VS2010 that will do just what you desire. And it's free!

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/872d27ee-38c7-4a97-98dc-0d8a431cc2ed

Comment: that's the solution I was looking for! Thanks Dan!!

Answer (score 2):

You could give Visual Assist X a go: http://www.wholetomato.com/

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I use the most excellent ViEmu plugin for visual studio, and it supplies the Vi(m) paren/brace/bracket matching.

ViEmu is [here](http://www.viemu.com)

Of course, if you're not a Vi lover, the price for matching parens may be too high. ;)