# how to enable matching braces option in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

now i am using vs2010 trail version.
i want to see the matching braces if there are multiple braces. the opening brace and the closing brace must be highlight.. how to achieve this?

Thank you,
Mihir

Comment: put your cursor behind the closing brace or before the opening brace, the matching brace will be highlighted light-gray

Comment: @Roman... i am using javascript in my code... it is not woriking for javascript...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link above should give you all default key mappings.

Another useful link is: [Pre-defined keyboard shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx)

I'd just like to mention a couple that I find very useful:

To jump back and forth between matching braces, you can put your cursor on either brace, and then push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>

And also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> toggles all outlining in the current file, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> toggles the current region

Comment: @Gustavo.. yes Ctrl-] works fine... it is directly going to the matching brace thank you..but it is very good if there is highligtning ...

Comment: Yeah :( Unfortunately, I'm not aware that Visual Studio provides this functionality out of the box. I think Resharper does this, but it's not a free plugin.

Answer (score 0):

from msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be94e8aw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

outlines all the options and how to set them up

for javascript: [Brace highlighting in Visual Studio for Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253338/brace-highlighting-in-visual-studio-for-javascript)

Comment: @Fourth.. thank you it help full really.. but my code contains javascript for javascript opening and closing tags it is not highlighting....

Comment: edited to include a stack overflow discussion on brace matching/highlighting in VS.